# Half Blood Prince and the Death Eaters at Diagon Alley

Tags: harry-potter

In the beginning of the Half Blood Prince, you can see death eaters blowing up the wall to diagon alley. So, wouldn’t the muggles be able to see and walk straight into the wizard world? Also I mean muggles that have no witch or wizard within the family.

Comment: muggles can already get into Diagon Alley - weren't Hermione's parents at Gringotts in Chamber of Secrets?

Comment: Yes, but I mean those who don’t have a witch or wizard in the family.

Comment: @JordanCarreira - I assume the Obliviators were extremely busy that day. The Death Eaters were successful in diverting valuable Ministry assets

Answer (score 5):

The Death Eaters flew in through the open door into the Leaky Cauldron, into the back yard, then through the (previously solid) wall that separates the Muggle world from the Wizarding world.

[image]

Since the baddies don't seem to have damaged the door to the pub, there's really no good reason to assume that the Ministry didn't prevent Muggles from seeing the Wizard world **by simply closing the door**.

---

That being said (and looking at the books), it would appear that the Cauldron already had Muggle-repelling charms cast on it. I think we can expect that these still worked just fine.

> It was a tiny, grubby-looking pub. If Hagrid hadn’t pointed it out, Harry wouldn’t have noticed it was there. **The people hurrying by didn’t glance at it. Their eyes slid from the big book shop on one side to the record shop on the other as if they couldn’t see the Leaky Cauldron at all.** In fact, Harry had the most peculiar feeling that only he and Hagrid could see it.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

and

> Dumbledore handed Riddle the envelope containing his list of equipment, and, after telling Riddle exactly how to get to the Leaky Cauldron from the orphanage, he said, **‘You will be able to see it, although Muggles around you – non-magical people, that is – will not.** Ask for Tom the barman – easy enough to remember, as he shares your name –’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

Comment: No need to close the door. 
"It was a tiny, grubby-looking pub. If Hagrid hadn’t pointed it out, Harry wouldn’t have noticed it was there. The people hurrying by didn’t glance at it. Their eyes slid from the big book shop on one side to the record shop on the other as if they couldn’t see the Leaky Cauldron at all. In fact, Harry had the most peculiar feeling that only he and Hagrid could see it. "

Comment: @Legion600 - A good point, well made. See edit

Comment: So, would muggles see Hagrid and Harry walking in, or do they disappear from sight when walking near the doors... if that makes any sense.

Comment: @JordanCarreira - Assuming the charms are similar to the ones at the train station, we can assume that Muggles just ignore what they can't understand. The occasional *inquisitive* Muggle might see something odd, but they'd be rapidly obliviated.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you all for helping me with this question.